# Need help with a simple Linq query running with Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4

Here's the code:

```
var userA = auction.UserAuctionLances.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTimeOfLance)
                                     .Select(u => u.User).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here's a view of the data in my database, specifically the UserAuctionLance table.

[image]

And here's a view of the tables relationships. Remember I'm using Entity Framework:

[image]

Basically, I want to get the **.Login** property of the last `User` who bid in the auction. However, my Linq query is fetching the very first user in the User table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks right-ish.  Maybe your relationships aren't correctly defined?

Comment: Turns out my problem was so incredibly dumb, I'll now go hang my head in shame. I was testing on my local machine and bidding using the real database. The DateTime.Now used to save the bid time was fetching time off my machine, obviously a bit further ahead than the time on the server. Oops! Hall of Shame™

Comment: This is why I hate "agile programming" with deadlines. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
var userA = auction.UserAuctionLances.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTimeOfLance).FirstOrDefault().User;
```